# Apt unmet dependencies while installing R on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, r

I wanted to install the new R version so I did a purge by removing all r-*. And then I broke everything unfortunately. I try to reinstall R project by typing

```
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

and then I obtain

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be 
               installed  
               Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable  
               Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable  
               Depends: libreadline7 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable  
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: You have held-broken packages.  Fix this first (ie. try `sudo apt -f install` & explore anything it reports, I would fix those first).  I'd also view the `apt` logs to see what you removed with your first listed command, and use that as a guide on fixing your system.  *I'd suggest closely avoiding using wildcards on remove commands unless you closely scrutinize what's being removed*

Comment: A quick look at the 16.04 repo reveals that the versions of the lib dependencies that are attempting to be installed are not part of the standard 16.04 distribution so they're not available.  Is it possible you're trying to install a newer version of R still such that the dependencies can't be met on your Ubuntu distro as is? https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/libs/

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb. I found out that I put the wrong source in my sources.list. I put `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/` instead of deb `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/`. Thank you !

Answer (score 13):

My problem is solved.

I had put the wrong source in my sources.list to download the latest version of R. Following the instructions given in https://cloud.r-project.org/, I had put `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu cosmic-cran35/` instead of `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/`.

By modifying the source, everything works fine now.

Comment: for the record: 16.04 === xenial, 18.04 === bionic, 18.10 === cosmic

Answer (score 2):

So here is **how to install R 3.6 on your current Ubuntu distribution**, without having to manually adjust the distribution name or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

# this will define the DISTRIB_* environment variables
source /etc/lsb-release

sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu ${DISTRIB_CODENAME}-cran35/"

# for 18.04, bionic beaver, this resolves to
#sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
# for 16.04, xenial, this resolves to
#sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev
R --version
Rscript --version
```

This should eliminate the error messages that arise from you choosing the wrong distribution like:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.23-0ubuntu11 is to be 
               installed  
               Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable  
               Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable  
               Depends: libreadline7 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable  
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Inspired by

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html
- https://uberubuntu.info/questions/319376/wie-erhalte-ich-den-distrib-codename

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libc6 libcurl4 libicu60-dev libreadline7
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

Comment: I added the wrong source in my sources.list. Instead of putting the xenial one, I put the cosmic one. By correcting this, everything seems to work now !

Comment: @Melebius Done !