# A problem in installing R in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dependencies, r

I've been trying without success to upgrade R in my Ubuntu 16.04 from 3.4 to the latest version in order to install some packages. Following some solutions, I did a purge by removing all r-*.   then everything broke.
I tried to install it again, but mistakenly, I've put the wrong source `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/` **instead of** `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/` as I have 16.04

I followed many suggestions to fix it and install R again (like [this](https://cloud.r-project.org/), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125448/apt-unmet-dependencies-while-installing-r-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031597/r-3-5-0-for-ubuntu)) but nothing worked and I am unable to install it again!

How I tried to install the complete R system:

```
sudo apt purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update
      


Err:28 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:29 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Translation-en_US
Ign:30 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Translation-en
Err:31 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:32 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Translation-en_US
Ign:33 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Translation-en
Fetched 465 kB in 4s (95,2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/disco-cran35/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran36/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

sudo apt-get install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Although that R complete system is not installed, I tried to obtain the latest R 4.0 packages as

```
sudo apt purge r-base* r-recommended r-cran-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:5 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease     
Hit:9 https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease              
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:11 https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease      
Hit:12 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease
Hit:13 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/ InRelease
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:15 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease             
Get:16 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:17 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ InRelease
Hit:18 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease
Ign:19 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ InRelease
Hit:20 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Err:21 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release
  404  Not Found
Err:22 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:23 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran36/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:69
W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71
W: Target Translations (en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71
W: Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:61 and /etc/apt/sources.list:71


sudo apt install r-base-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Could you please help me to install again R

Edit: Adding the following lines didn't help!

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you installed required  dependencies?

Comment: Try installing it by `sudo apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common
`

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'` Try adding this source, I think you enter wrong source.

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9`

Comment: Thanks @InjamulMohammadMollah for comments. I added the dependencies, modified the source and the key as you suggested but, unfortunately, the same problem!

Comment: ```sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install r-base``` Run this.

Comment: @InjamulMohammadMollah Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.2-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be i

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1013171/1071912 also follow this for more info.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. purge old packages and source, then follow the instruction in the given link. It might help you.

Comment: if  you like to install r from ppa then try this https://askubuntu.com/a/919288/1071912 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`

Comment: @InjamulMohammadMollah No it didn't! I tried all the suggested ways but I still have the same problem!!